# ibase query - do not show data

Tags: php, firebird

i have this query to get data from database (firebird DB) and print it into the table ...

```
    <?php

   $dbh = ibase_pconnect("pathtoDB", "SYSDBA", "masterkey") or die('die message');
    $q = ibase_query($dbh, "select sc.code as kod, sc.name as nazov, ssc.Quantity as mnozstvo, ssc.LowLimitQuantity as limit
from storecards sc
join storesubcards ssc on ssc.StoreCard_ID = sc.ID
where sc. X_Visible = 'A' and ssc.Store_ID = '2000000101' ");
```

table ....

```
while ($r = ibase_fetch_row($q)) {
        $code = $r->kod;
        $name = $r->nazov;
        $mnozstvo = $r->mnozstvo;
        $limit = $r->limit;


        echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $kod . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $nazov . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $mnozstvo . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $limit . "</td>";

echo "</tr>";
    }   

echo "</table>";     

?>
```

but my result is empty data from table, it shows only count of rows

Comment: Seems like you might need `ibase_fetch_object($q)` instead of `ibase_fetch_row($q)`, as you're attempting to access it as properties of an object, and not elements in an array. You also have some undefined variables, `$code` != `$kod` and `$name` != `$nazov`.

Comment: i tried this one but not working : `while ($r = ibase_fetch_object($q)) {
        $code = $r->code;
  $name = $r->name;
  $mnozstvo = $r->mnozstvo;
  $limit = $r->limit;
  
        
  echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $code. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $name. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $mnozstvo . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $limit . "</td>";`

Comment: @MartinJašek It should be `$code=$r->$r->kod;` and `$name = $r->nazov;` as those are the columns (or the alias you set) in your database query

Comment: i have empty table like this [https://i.imgur.com/v65ccBd.png] actually i tried this code but not working : `while ($r = ibase_fetch_object($q)) {
        $code=$r->kod;
  $name = $r->name;
  $mnozstvo = $r->mnozstvo;
  $limit = $r->limit;
  
        
  echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $code. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $name. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $mnozstvo . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $limit . "</td>";`

Comment: what's the result of `print_r($r)`

Comment: @WillParky93, it showing all data from table, for example : `stdClass Object ( [KOD] => 7P0201021J [NAZOV] => NF 100L hybrid [MNOZSTVO] => 4.000000 [LIMIT] => 2.000000 )`

Comment: @MartinJašek Please look at my updated answer for what your code inside the while loop should be. Variables are case sensitive.

Comment: great @WillParky93 , problem is with upper case, when i edit it like this : `$code=$r->KOD;
  $name = $r->NAZOV;
  $mnozstvo = $r->MNOZSTVO;
  $limit = $r->LIMIT;` working like charm

Comment: @MartinJašek great to hear, if my answer helped you please upvote and mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You've mixed up your variable names.

```
$code = $r->KOD;
$name = $r->NAZOV;
$mnozstvo = $r->MNOZSTVO;
$limit = $r->LIMIT;

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $code. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $name. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $mnozstvo . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $limit . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```